# D3.js - Zooming while keeping sizes, with d3.forceSimulation()

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming, simulation

I have a graph visualisation.
I've added zooming by scaling a `<g>` which holds everything.
That also resizes the nodes (circles) and their labels.

From what I've seen, keeping the size and only repositioning is done [like this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2a39a768b1d4bc00a09650edef75ad39):

```
function zoomed() {
    var t = d3.event.transform;
    circle.attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + t.applyX(d[0]) + "," + t.applyY(d[1]) + ")";
    });
}
```

However this won't work for me, because I already use translate for positioning the nodes by `d3.forceSimulation()`. I could apply the zoom like it's done above, but that would all fall back when the simulation gets started again - e.g. when dragging a node, which is done using:

```
function dragstarted() {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    ...
```

**How could I combine the simulation and the zooming?**

- One way I am thinking is to scale down all the nodes by inverse scale to what is used for zooming.
- Other way could be styling down the things - smaller font, smaller circles, etc.
- Other way could be tampering with the forces so the nodes go further from each other on zoom in.

Answer (score 0):

For now I went the way of reversed scale for each node. Works quite fine, although it's a little bit of overhead I think.

Here's the code:

```
// Zooming
var zoom = d3.zoom();
zoom.scaleExtent([0.4, 3]);
zoom.on("zoom", function onZoomed() {
    console.log("Zooming", d3.event);
    var t = d3.event.transform;
    zoomingGroup.attr("transform", t); // Using transform.toString()
    svg.selectAll(".myGroup circle").attr("transform", "scale(" + 1/t.k + ")");
    svg.selectAll(".myGroup .labelBox").attr("transform", "scale(" + 1/t.k + ")");
    svg.selectAll(".myGroup .labelText").attr("transform", "scale(" + 1/t.k + ")");
});
```

I wanted to apply it to the whole `<g class=".myGroup">`, but changing it's `transform` to scale would interfere with `forceSimulation()`'s `translate`. Can you give me a tip to handle that? I could add another `<g>` and apply `translate(...)` to the parent `<g>` and `scale(...)` to the other.

I'm leaving this unaccepted in case someone has better (simpler) solution.